# Swipe option missing on JellyBean keyboard

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, keyboard

I have Micromax A116 running on 4.2 JellyBean, rooted and using NatureWiz HD rom. However, I don't have swipe feature on my keyboard.

Am I missing some settings that I have to turn on?

Comment: What manufacturer made your phone or tablet? Some manufacturers add their own keyboard in place of Google's keyboard.

Comment: it is micromax A116 rooted, naturewiz hd rom.